# How to determin type of variable at runtime

Tags: c#, generics

I have a list of different types. classes have common base classes and a common interface:

```
 public List<IColumn> columnTypes = new List<IColumn>
        {        
        new Column1(),
        new Column2(),
        new Column3()
        };
```

Now I need a variable c:

```
c = columnTypes[x];
```

where x is determined at runtime and therefore c will have its type determined at runtime.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can use reflection

Comment: `columnTypes[x].GetType()` ?

Comment: If you are abstracting to interfaces, then why the need to use implementation details? Seems like your design could be improved.

Comment: What do you intend to do with `c`? The answer to that will determine the best answer to your question!

Comment: Indeed I needed to review the design: the difference between Column1 and Column2 type is really a difference inside a List<T> within the Column-s: The List<T> can have differently typed elements (via an interface, as some respondents showed), but that does not necessarily make the type of Column1 different from the type of Column2. I think. Now.

Answer (score 3):

You have an interface (`IColumn`)... you should use your `Column*` from that interface.

```
IColumn c = columnTypes[x];

c.Foo(); // where Foo is a method defined in IColumn and implemented in Column*
```

If you want you can:

```
Column1 c1 = c as Column1;

if (c1 != null)
{
    c1.SpecificFooC1(); // "special" method of Column1
}
```

or

```
if (c1 is Column1)
{
    // Here we were only interested in knowing if c1 was Column1
}
```

Comment: wouldn't work if he implements other methods than those of the interface that he needs to use

Comment: @Coder1409 There is an example that is exactly about this, the second one.

Comment: He just Can use reflection for this , don't why reflection gives people the creeps , and you're 100% sure it works

Answer (score 1):

why  not use a variable of interface type

```
   IColumn  c  = columnTypes[x];
```

if your type does not fully  implement the interface IColumn
you can use `columnTypes[x].GetType()`  but this will  need some additional coding

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = columnTypes[x];
```

`c.GetType()` will give you the `Type` object, with all the information you need: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) is an overview.